# How to update the foreign key in a one-to-many relationship mapped with EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created a one-to-many relationship using the EF convention for that. Then after the `update-database` I got a `Company_CompanyId` column in the `WorkRoles` table, which was the desired result.

But when I tried to actually use this foreign key, so I can connect the different roles with different companies I got stuck.

In my `WorkRoleController` I expected to see be able to access the FK property in the way I can access the other properties, but this wasn't the case.

When I type `workrole(dot)` I see the `RoleName`, `RoleDescription`, `WorkRoleId` and, instead of `Company_CompanyId`, I see just `Company`. Which is the object `Company`, not the foreign key.

So my question is, how can I use that foreign key, so when creating a new role I can do something like :

```
Company company = db.Companies.Where(c => c.CAId == currentUserId)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

int companyID = company.CompanyId;    // find the company for the current user

workRole.Company_CompanyId = companyID;    // save the company ID to the FK field.
```

Can someone help with that? How can I actually save a foreign key when saving a `workrole`?

Role model :

```
public class WorkRole
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Company model :

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadImage { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string ImageBase64 => System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CAId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WorkRole> WorkRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but what should i do with public virtual Company Company { get; set; } then?

Comment: You may want to look into *foreign key associations* vs. *independent associations*.

Comment: should i use the foreign key attribute, in your opinion, or just public int CompanyId { get; set; } will be okay, @GertArnold

Comment: okay, thanks, I will look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `CompanyId`property to your WorkRole class, push changes to the database and then you should see it when you type workrole(dot) and update it as you like.

```
public class WorkRole
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId {get; set;}// this will be mapped as foreign key by EF convention.
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

If your foreign key property name doesn't follow any of the EF conventions, you can use `[ForeignKey]` data annotation to let EF know that the property you just defined is actually the foreign key:

```
public class WorkRole
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Company")]
        public int Foo {get; set;}
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

You can also use it on the navigation property:

```
public class WorkRole
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int WorkRoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
        public int Foo {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("Foo")]
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```